# embedded linux on arm processor creating android image from given source

Tags: android, embedded, embedded-linux

how can we build a image of android OS from the given source?? it is for my embedded system project in which arm processor is used

Comment: Can you provide the details of the architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an advanced question - firstly there are many hardware drivers which you have to make sure that the Android kernel have.   Normally, the vendor that provide the hardware would have already ported the Android kernel to run on it.   What is the name of the hardware?

Higher level OS/applications issues are discussed here:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-porting

A paper focusing on the kernel / bootloader porting is described here:

http://hsc.com/Portals/0/Uploads/Articles/Android-Porting-on-Embedded-Platform_v2_0633850602027036930.pdf

Comment: thanks for the links.. am using ferret board in which the processor module is ATBN421js